# Compile assembly in Cmake with MSVC on Windows x64

Tags: windows, assembly, cmake

I tried compile asm in Visual Studio with cmake. I have main.cpp, JustValue.asm. My CmakeList.txt look like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

project(
    asm_test
    LANGUAGES CXX
)

enable_language(C ASM)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp JustValue.asm)

set_target_properties(
        ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
        CXX_STANDARD 20
        CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON
)
```

main.cpp :

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" int JustValue();

int main() {
    std::cout << "Value = " << JustValue() << std::endl;
}
```

and asm file:

```
.code 

JustValue proc

    mov eax, 7

    ret
JustValue endp
end
```

And linker generate the error

```
>------ Build started: Project: CMakeLists, Configuration: Debug ------
  [1/3] Building ASM object CMakeFiles\asm_test.dir\JustValue.asm.obj
  Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.32.31332 for x64
  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
 
C:\Users\ruden\source\repos\asm_test\out\build\x64-Debug\cl : Command line warning D9035: option 'o' has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release
C:\Users\ruden\source\repos\asm_test\out\build\x64-Debug\cl : Command line warning D9024: unrecognized source file type 'C:\Users\ruden\source\repos\asm_test\JustValue.asm', object file assumed
C:\Users\ruden\source\repos\asm_test\out\build\x64-Debug\cl : Command line warning D9027: source file 'C:\Users\ruden\source\repos\asm_test\JustValue.asm' ignored
C:\Users\ruden\source\repos\asm_test\out\build\x64-Debug\cl : Command line warning D9021: no action performed
  [2/3] Building CXX object CMakeFiles\asm_test.dir\main.cpp.obj
  [3/3] Linking CXX executable asm_test.exe
  FAILED: asm_test.exe 
  cmd.exe /C "cd . && "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\asm_test.dir --rc=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100190~1.0\x64\rc.exe --mt=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100190~1.0\x64\mt.exe --manifests  -- C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1\2022\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1432~1.313\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe /nologo CMakeFiles\asm_test.dir\main.cpp.obj CMakeFiles\asm_test.dir\JustValue.asm.obj  /out:asm_test.exe /implib:asm_test.lib /pdb:asm_test.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:x64 /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console  kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib && cd ."
  LINK Pass 1: command "C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1\2022\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1432~1.313\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe /nologo CMakeFiles\asm_test.dir\main.cpp.obj CMakeFiles\asm_test.dir\JustValue.asm.obj /out:asm_test.exe /implib:asm_test.lib /pdb:asm_test.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:x64 /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:CMakeFiles\asm_test.dir/intermediate.manifest CMakeFiles\asm_test.dir/manifest.res" failed (exit code 1104) with the following output:
C:\Users\ruden\source\repos\asm_test\out\build\x64-Debug\LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'CMakeFiles\asm_test.dir\JustValue.asm.obj'
  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

What should I do to fix this error?

Comment: Add the error message into the **question post** as **text**. This is how Stack Overflow works: all information relevant to the problem should be in the question post itself, not linked.

Comment: `cl` is the C / C++ compiler.  You're running it on your `.asm` file.  I think the command to run MASM is `ml` or something like that.  IDK how you get cmake to run it, but I think there are some earlier Q&As on Stack Overflow about that.

Answer (score 2):

I needed single line! I replaced enable_language(C ASM) with enable_language(C ASM_MASM)

```
enable_language(C ASM_MASM)
```

thanks https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/21462